poly-filler in this particular sentence
In this article, a paragraph reads,

In my makeup bag there is an arsenal of tools which I use to tear down the patriarchy. In my makeup bag there is a bunch of cremes, potions, poly-filler and over-the-counter drugs that allow me to cross an overbearing gender binary.

I am not sure about the meaning of poly-filler here. When I look it up, all I can find is a kind of substance for filling cracks or holes. When put in the context of makeup, it doesn't make much sense though. Is there any other meaning for poly-filler? Or does the author of the article truly mean the substance used in interior design??

Under the skin, women have a 1/7 of an inch layer of fat that men don't have. Lotions, potions, and fillers may give a desired puffiness.

In case it's not clear... Polyfilla is a trade name

The OP is asking about poly-filler, which is not a trade name. Several companies make them, for example.

Don't both 'which I use to tear down the patriarchy' and 'that allow me to cross an overbearing gender binary' suggest this is much more allegorical than anything literal about a make-up bag?
The newer the citation, the more likely 'poly-filler' is either a generic term for any kind of cosmetic filler, or a jocular reference to architectural Polyfilla.

You can find pollyfiller used in the sense of makeup in the OED under . . .

Polyfilla noun Chiefly British.
1. A proprietary name for: a type of plaster-like filler used to make minor building repairs. In extended use, usually humorous (also
polyfilla, polyfiller): a substance used to hide small imperfections, esp. make-up. 1956– [selected
attestation:] 1989   She refused to meet any of
my scruffy acquaintances without make-up and, as she had banned the
polyfiller for the day, we would not be going to the Queen’s Arms.
—Courier-Mail (Brisbane) (Nexis) 1 March 7

This definition is tagged cosmetics, British English, and humorous. Note also the second definition:

2. figurative (also polyfilla, polyfiller). Usually depreciative. Something used to fill a gap or hide faults, esp. superfluous language. Frequently attributive. 1979–
[selected attestation:] 2004   Whatever
setlist Bowie’s been using he lost it on his way here, leaving us
little more than a meandering mess of generic B-sides and lesser-known
polyfillers. —Ottawa Sun (Nexis) 3 April 27

This definition is tagged British English and depreciative.
Lastly, note that if you use the top navigation menu at Refinery 29 (the source of your quote) to switch from United Kingdom to United States, your polly-filler becomes Poly-Fil.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

The comparison has been around for a while.

If it helps you be a good friend to yourself, spend thousands on
cosmetic surgery. But the person inside all the sticking plaster and
poly-filler and all the glue and wallpaper paste and smoke and mirrors,
that person is you. There is no plastic surgery for the soul.
Paul
Barrass; Amazing Friendships (2006)


There is an art to botox which has been lost by pumping it into the
face like poly-filler.
The Spectator, Vol. 304, p.43 (2007)


There is a (2016) article by the Daily Mirror (no pun intended) in which the term 'Polyfilla' is used whimsically for smoothing facial rather than architectural blemishes:

Can you really Polyfilla wrinkles away? What the experts say.
How
effective are facial fillers? Daily Mirror journalist Kim Jones asked
eight readers to try them out....

It is non-standard but (from purely a language standpoint; legality may be a different matter) totally acceptable (being a transparent broadening) in informal registers. Use with care.

People also talk about applying make-up with a trowel which is a similar "heavy makeup=wall-finishing" joke - the trowel is the sort used for plastering not gardening. Polyfilla does appear to be a trademark of AkzoNobel but it's one of those trademarks that is widely used in a generic sense (like xerox, hoover, etc)

@StuartF Yes,  quite so. Don’t understand why Edwin described it as nonstandard. Edwin?

The number of relevant hits on Google. The lack of a definition for this sense in dictionaries. Still a niche metaphor.

I have heard the term "poly-filler" used ironically or disparagingly to refer to make-up which can be used to fill and thus conceal wrinkles and other perceived blemishes on a person's face.
